# Java: difference between drawing over brand new image vs over loaded image

Tags: java, png, awt, bufferedimage, graphics2d

There was a PHP application that's purpose was to print text over a number of pre-defined PNG images.
It worked without issues and printed antialiased text in any given font and color.
What are the special considerations when printing over the existing images in Java?

I tired to use Graphics2D calls to print over the same images, but it is not working with the code below.

```
String imName = Config.getBlanketImage();
File file = new File(imName);
// BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(400, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
// graphics.setColor(new Color(bColor.getRed(), bColor.getGreen(), bColor.getBlue()));
// graphics.fillRect(0, 0, im.getWidth(), im.getHeight());
BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(file);

graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_DISABLE);
graphics.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER));
graphics.setFont(drawFont);
graphics.setColor(new Color(aColor.getRed(), aColor.getGreen(), a.getBlue()));
graphics.drawString(Config.getText1(), x, y);
```

The text comes across in a completely wrong color - the shades of background, sometimes surrounded by thin line of black pixels. I cannot post images and only 2 links, so screw the samples.
But if I commented out the first three lines and uncommented the commented out lines and printed over a brand new image, the colors would be correct and anti-aliasing would be on.

I tried with and without the rendering hints and it did not make any difference whatsoever, just showing all that I tried.

Comment: Is your test image truecolor RGB(A) or does it use a palette?

Comment: Good catch. Saving images as 24bit fixed everything. Sounds like PHP does not care about 8 bit color depth, but AWT does.

Comment: Other than the fact that the files are now 10x times larger, it works. Is there any way to print over 8bit color depth just like PHP did? Moving to the truecolor images will bloat our traffic and memory requirements.

Comment: You'll have to disable antialiasing and transparency, at least. Or convert to 24 bits, add text, convert back to 8-bit.

Comment: *"pre-defined PNG images."*  Link to one (that is preferably small in bytes).

Comment: @Jongware You'll get the best results by going to true color and then add a new color quantization/dithering step, but it's also possible to keep the `IndexColorModel` from the original image if the color you use to paint text is already in the palette.

Comment: Harald, did you mean it is possible to keep 8bit images and temporarily convert them to 24bit to perform drawing, then convert back to 8? Could you provide a sample?